# calculated field combining multiple fields into one

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013, calculated-field

I'm trying to create a value in a calculated field based on a 4 digit Autonumber, first letter of firstname, and lastname to create a username. I'm intending to create something like this username -> flastname0001.

Here is what I'm using for my expression:
LCase(Left([firstname],1) & [lastname]) & Left([idnumber],4)

I have 0000 in the format for the idnumber field and set to long integer and increment.

No matter what I have tried this is the only result I can get:

Table:

```
idnumber = 0001
firstname = John
lastname = Doe
(calculated field) username = jdoe1
```

Anyone know how to make the username field create jdoe0001?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Left()` will give you the number of characters you request when the source string contains at least that number of characters.  But when the source string contains fewer characters than requested, `Left()` gives you the source string.

Here is an example from the Immediate window:

```vb
? Left("abcde", 4)
abcd
? Left("a", 4)
a
```

In your case, you have a numeric field with a format.  So when the field contains *1*, that value is **displayed as** *0001*.  However, the actual stored value is just *1*, without the leading zeros.  And when you give the field's value to `Left()`, it operates on the un-formatted number *1*:

```vb
idnumber = 1
? Left(idnumber, 4)
1
' which is equivalent to this ...
? Left(CStr(idnumber), 4)
1
```

Since you want the leading zeros, you can apply your format to *idnumber* when you feed it to `Left()`:

```vb
? Left(Format(idnumber, "0000"), 4)
0001
```

But using both `Left()` and `Format()` there seems like overkill.  If *idnumber* never contains more than 4 digits, just `Format()` will give you what you need:

```vb
? Format(idnumber, "0000")
0001
```

So your original expression could become ...

```vb
LCase(Left([firstname],1) & [lastname]) & Format(idnumber, "0000")
```

Finally, make sure the 4-digits requirement is what you will always want.  Long Integer can accommodate numbers up to *2,147,483,647*.

That approach works for a calculated field in a query.  But if you want to define a calculated field in a table, `Format()` is not available.  In that case, you can concatenate *"0000"* and *idnumber*, and use `Right()` to grab the last 4 characters:

```vb
? Right("0000" & idnumber, 4)
0001
```

Comment: This works in my query perfectly, which is what I really needed anyway.

I was wondering, though, would something like this work with a Calculated field in a table? If so, how would you write that out? Format isn't a built-In Function for expressions.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize `Format()` is not usable for a table calculated field.  I added a workaround.  I tested it in Access 2010 and it works as I think you want.

Comment: That is fine, didn't really need it to work in the table since I am using the query to generate a CSV file anyway. I was just wondering if there was a way for calculated fields. I never use them since I use SQL for my calculations and I just wanted to play around with the calculated data type in tables. :)

And I just saw your edit! Awesome! Thank you very much for your time.